# Access Query to return custom quarters from a date field

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

If someone could help me out on this problem. This company's quarter starts as follows where the numbers represent the months and the  Q's are the quarters.

```
Q1 = 9, 10, 11
Q2 = 12, 1, 2
Q3 = 3, 4, 5
Q4 = 6, 7, 8
```

I am trying to make a query a that returns the number 1, 2, 3, 4 for dates that fall within the quarters. I have researched and came across this approach but doesn't work correctly because I don't know how to handle `Iif` and `Between` functions.

`Quarter: Iif(Month([MyDate]) Between 9 And 11, 1, Iif(Month([MyDate]) Between 12 And 2, 2, Iif(Month([MyDate]) Between 3 And 5, 3, 4)))`

Comment: For quarter crossing multiple years, separate 12 and the first months: `...IIF((Month([MyDate]) == 12) OR (Month([MyDate]) BETWEEN 1 And 2), 2, ...`

Comment: This may not be necessary as the query already includes the year part and month parts.

Comment: But @Fil, no value is ever `BETWEEN 12 and 2`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler method uses `datepart()` -- but 4 months later:

```
select datepart("q", dateadd("m", 4, mydate)) as my_quarter
```